# File.OpenRead and GetFileAsync

Tags: wpf

What's the difference between:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myFile.txt");
```

and

```
File.OpenRead( ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\myFile.txt" );
```

Comment: ... one is async and one is not?

Comment: @Jashaszun I would think there is some more substantial difference.  IE, one is scoped to a certain user's directory and the other one can access any file or something like that.

Comment: What are you asking? You are mixing up a Windows Store call with a normal .NET Framework call. You can't use `File.OpenRead` in a Windows Store application. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why can't I use File.OpenRead? It is there in intellisense.  What's the difference?

Comment: @AndyzSmith It's for security reasons. Windows Store apps don't get the full .NET API.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel From my testing on Visual Studio 2012, and Windows 8.0 Emulator both function the same (except for the async perhaps).  Are you saying that when deployed to 'Store' this function, available and working in the Emulator, will be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Both can be used, but `GetFileAsync` will not *block* the execution until the full file is returned.

To use it you will need to put in an `await` such as:

`var result = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("myFile.txt");`

Why use await?

Async installs a certain overhead in handling things like timeouts and what not in the background so you the foreground developer does not have to directly deal with it.

Primarily use it to not block GUI operations or when there is need to load multiple facets of data that do not rely on a synchronous chaining of the data extractions.

To understand start by reading Stephen Cleary's blog article [Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: So, to fill out the pattern here, the method I write needs to be Async right?  And any method that calls my method needs to await it. And that method needs to be tagged async? Where does it end?  The only place I see it ending is in an Event Handler, like button click, which ties closely into the UI task switching framework.  The point is, I actually don't care about the async, and would rather use the other one.  What's the difference/is that the ONLY difference?

Comment: @AndyzSmith One can call a an asynchronous method synchronously by removing the `await` and extracting the data from task structure returned; but why add the overhead and simply use the non-async methods? Async installs a certain overhead in handling things like timeouts and what not in the background so you the foreground developer does not have to directly deal with it.

Comment: Task structure is not valid until you do Task.Wait() and poll Task.IsCompleted - is that right?

Comment: @AndyzSmith if one is polling the task, yes 'IsCompleted' can be checked TAP async patterns. See [Asynchronous Programming Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So basically to get a synchronous task, Task.Wait( timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)), if (Task.IsCompleted) { var X = Task.Result }.  Really if something blocks for more than 10 seconds, I just want an exception.